# What is the best way to return Json array?

Tags: arrays, json

I want to return an array of all users in json format.
Which choice is better to use?

Choice A

```
[
  {
    first_name: "aaa",
    last_name: "aaa"
  },
  {
    first_name: "bbb",
    last_name: "bbb"
  },
]
```

Choice B

```
{
  users: [
    {
      first_name: "aaa",
      last_name: "aaa"
    },
    {
      first_name: "bbb",
      last_name: "bbb"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does “better” mean?

Comment: To be honest, it's really up to you.  While Choice B does have a minor benefit, in that it describes the data contents (ie. so that the people in the dataset don't get confused with "customers", for example), the reality is that if you're serving up Choice A when someone hits a "/users" API endpoint, then the particular endpoint already defines what to expect in the dataset.  I certainly wouldn't say that either way is definitely right, or either way is definitely wrong

Comment: Thank you. I understood either way is fine. I haven’t seen choice B with “/users” api endpoints. So I was not sure if I can use choice b or not.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is "better," it simply depends on what you might need to use them for.

The former option allows for addition of new top level entities.  You could add another top level entity for example

```json
{
   "users": ...,
   "systems": ...
}
```

This could be helpful in an API for example.  If you're returning data and think it might change or get additions later, this could be a non breaking way to do that.

It also requires that when you're accessing the data you need to access into that dictionary, for example to get the 0th element you would do something like

```
my_data["users"][0]
```

The latter option doesn't allow you to add more top level entities (unless you switch back to the former).  But you could access the data with one less access

```
my_data[0]
```

Neither of these are "better".  It simply depends on what you're using the data for.  How might it change?  Who is looking at it?  etc

Comment: Thank you. I understood both of them are fine. And I need to choose the one depending on a situation.

Comment: I was not sure if it is fine to use choice B because I haven’t seen them that much when I hit api endpoint (ex /users, or /meetings ) to fetch data.